# Tensorflowを用いたロジスティック回帰で重みがnanになる

Tags: python, tensorflow

『[機械学習 はじめよう 第20回](http://gihyo.jp/dev/serial/01/machine-learning/0020)』を参考にして、ロジスティック回帰をTensorflowを用いて実装しようと考えていますが、重み・バイアスがすぐにnanになってしまいます。

調べたところ、対数尤度関数のlogが怪しい、ということでlogの中身に小さい数（1e-5など）を足してみたりしましたが変わりませんでした。

Tensorflowにも不慣れですので他の部分にも不具合があるかもしれません。
何が原因と考えられますでしょうか。
ご教授いただければ幸いです。

list: logistic_tf.py

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def sigmoid(z):
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + tf.exp(-z))

x_d = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 2), name='x_d')
t_d = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, ), name='t_d')

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2, 1]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
t = sigmoid(tf.matmul(x_d, W) + b)

loss = - tf.reduce_sum(t_d * tf.log(t) + (1 - t_d) * tf.log(1 - t))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

# create data set
def h(x, y):
    return 5 * x + 3 * y - 1
x_data = np.random.randn(100, 2).astype('float32')
t_data = np.array([1 if h(x, y) > 0 else 0 for x, y in x_data])

for step in range(200):
    sess.run(train, feed_dict={x_d: x_data, t_d: t_data})
    if step % 10 == 0:
        print(step, sess.run(W), sess.run(b))
        # W = [[5], [3]], b = [-1], expected

sess.close()
```

9/27追記
学習率を0.1から0.01, 0.001と下げたところ、0.01ではnanになりました。0.001ではnanは回避できましたが、期待される値とは別のところで振動してしまいました。損失関数が間違っているということでしょうか。どのように修正すべきでしょうか。

学習率0.001のときの出力

```
0 [[ 0.33279842]
 [-0.0880626 ]] [-1.4000001]
1000 [[ 1.2017732 ]
 [-0.18360852]] [-2.0046742]
2000 [[ 1.2017722 ] 
 [-0.18360843]] [-2.0046737]
3000 [[ 1.2017732 ]
 [-0.18360852]] [-2.0046742]
4000 [[ 1.2017722 ]
 [-0.18360843]] [-2.0046737]
5000 [[ 1.2017732 ]
 [-0.18360852]] [-2.0046742]
6000 [[ 1.2017722 ]
 [-0.18360843]] [-2.0046737]
7000 [[ 1.2017732 ]
 [-0.18360852]] [-2.0046742]
8000 [[ 1.2017722 ]
 [-0.18360843]] [-2.0046737]
9000 [[ 1.2017732 ]
 [-0.18360852]] [-2.0046742]
```

Comment: 学習率(optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1)の0.1部分)を0.001等下げても発生しますでしょうか

Comment: @H.H コメントありがとうございます。質問を編集しましたので、よろしければご覧ください

Comment: 「logの中身に小さい数（1e-5など）を足してみたり」と記載してあるので、logの中身は0になっていないものと判断します。振動とおっしゃられていますが、ログに表示しているのは重みとバイアスのようです。収束具合を確認したのであればlossの値もログに出力した方が良いと思います。(tensorboardを使用した方が楽かと思います。)。その上でloss関数の値が振動しているのであればまだ学習率が高いということになるかと思います。

Comment: すみません、文章のみ見ておりコード部分をよく見ていなかったのですが二つ問題がありそうです。1.学習データの生成がループの外なので毎回同じデータを使用している 2.ラベルの形が[None]となっており。データ全体での評価をしている(1回の入力データ全ての結果に対して評価している)。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2点問題がありそうです
1. 学習データの作成がループの外で1回のみ行われ1回の学習でそのデータを全て使っており
　　毎回同じ学習となっている。
2. ラベルの形が[None]となっており、教師データ正解全体で評価がなされている

上記修正したところ2000回の学習で
W:[[13.174871],[ 7.863011]] b:[-2.5919526]となり
元の式に対してスカラ倍した形の式(2.6*(5x+3y-1))に近い形になっており正解と言えそうです。

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def sigmoid(z):
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + tf.exp(-z))

x_d = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 2), name='x_d')
t_d = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1), name='t_d') # [1]をラベルとする

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2, 1]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
t = sigmoid(tf.matmul(x_d, W) + b)

#loss = - tf.reduce_sum(t_d * tf.log(t) + (1 - t_d) * tf.log(1 - t))
loss = -tf.reduce_sum(t_d * tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(t,1e-10,1.0)) + (1 - t_d) * tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(1-t,1e-10,1.0))) #log(0)対策
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

# create data set
def h(x, y):
    return 5 * x + 3 * y - 1


for step in range(2000):
    x_data = np.random.randn(100, 2).astype('float32')
    t_data = np.array([[1] if h(x, y) > 0 else [0] for x, y in x_data]) #[None,1]の形で返す
    sess.run(train, feed_dict={x_d: x_data, t_d: t_data})
    if step % 10 == 0:
        print(step, sess.run(W), sess.run(b))
        print(step,sess.run(loss,feed_dict={x_d: x_data, t_d: t_data}))
        # W = [[5], [3]], b = [-1], expected

sess.close()
```

なお、今回はログに学習進捗を出力していますが
学習進捗はtensorboardを使用した方が便利かと思います。
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/summaries_and_tensorboard

また、sigmoid関数やcrossentroy関数も自前で定義せずともAPIとして用意されているのでそちらもご確認ください。
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/sigmoid_cross_entropy

Comment: 毎回同じデータを使って学習していることについては、確かに問題ではありますが今回はモデルが正しいことが分かっているので、nanが出現する直接の原因ではないと思っていたのですが、そうではないということでしょうか。

Comment: 2. のご指摘について修正を行ったところ、たしかにスカラー倍の式が得られました。ありがとうございました。スカラー不変なパラメータであることを全く考えていませんでした。

Comment: はい、1.につきましては気になった点として記載させて頂きました。ご認識通り直接の原因ではありません。